# Is branching from branchA which itself branched from master, same as branching from master, and then merging changes from another branch of master?

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Scenario 1:**

- We have master.
- git checkout -b branchA (branched out off master)
- git checkout -b branchB (branched out off branchA)
- branchA was merged.
- git checkout branchB
- git pull origin master (master changes pulled into branchB)
- //This is the end state

**Scenario 2:**

- We have master.
- git checkout -b branchA (branched out off master)
- git checkout master
- git checkout -b branchB (branched out off master)
- git pull origin branchA (Pull in branchA changes into branchB)
- branchA merged into master
- git pull origin master
- //end state.

Are both these scenarios same?

Comment: Git pull origin master - will not pull changes into branch B. It will just update your local master with changes from remote origin. Since you did not do any changes and if there is no changes in remote repo, branching multiple times and merging will not change the state. All the branches will still point to the last commit.

Comment: You never commit anything to any of the branches. Is that intentional?

Comment: It's just a mess in your description. Branch is not created from another branch, branch are based on commit, a branch is just a pointer point to a commit. You's better learn the basic git concept from [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: What do you mean "branchA was merged." in Scenario 1?

Comment: By saying "git pull origin branchA in Scenario 2", it seems you also misunderstood pull and merge concept, actually it's a merge operation. And since branch A and branch B in Scenario 2 point to same commit, there is no need to do the merge operation.  At last, git pull is not a good habit, git fetch first and review the changes, then decide to use  git merge or git rebase is a better operation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't branch from a branch, you branch from the commit the branch refers to. If master and branchA refer to the same commit, let's call it ABC123, then all of these are the same.

```
git branch branchB master
git branch branchB branchA
git branch branchB ABC123
```

In all cases branchB will point at commit ABC123. From that point forward, what happens to master or branchA has no effect on branchB.

For example...

```
A - B [master]

$ git branch branchA
$ git branch branchB

A - B [master]
      [branchA]
      [branchB]
```

All three branches point at commit B.

If we then checkout branchA and make some commits...

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ ...git commit...
$ ...git commit...

      C - D [branchA]
     /
A - B [master]
      [branchB]
```

master and branchB remain at commit B. branchA goes off on its own. If we then checkout branchB and make some commits...

```
$ git checkout branchB
$ ...git commit...
$ ...git commit...

      C - D [branchA]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      E - F [branchB]
```

Now branchB goes off on its own. And if we do the same for master...

```
$ git checkout master
$ ...git commit...
$ ...git commit...

      C - D [branchA]
     /
A - B - G - H [master]
     \
      E - F [branchB]
```

master goes off on its own.

---

The rest of your scenario is confused because this is incorrect.

```
git pull origin master (master changes pulled into branchB)
```

This pulls changes from origin/master to master.

If you wanted to pull origin/master into branchB you would use `git pull origin master:branchB`. The full syntax is `git pull <remote> +<src>:<dest>`. This is usually used as just `git pull <remote> <src>`.